# basic sql syntax how do I reference my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to get the below code to work for what I needed but only when I include the prefix "use" at the top.  When I try to include the name of the database in the "where" clause, I was unsuccessful (would get back column headers and no rows).

What syntax do I need to use to reference the database object without using "use"?

(Note: This question is for my own curiosity.  the "use" prefix effectively solves my problem for running the metadata query.)

---

```
use [Investment Data 1]
SELECT 
    c.name 'Column Name',
    t.Name 'Data type',
    c.max_length 'Max Length',
    c.precision ,
    c.scale ,
    c.is_nullable,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.hurricane_landfall_2017')
```

Comment: You can probably use *fully qualified names*: `[Investment Data 1].sys.columns`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the databasename to each object, there's a four part naming syntax in SQL Server: `server.database.schema.object`

```
SELECT 
    c.name 'Column Name',
    t.Name 'Data type',
    c.max_length 'Max Length',
    c.precision ,
    c.scale ,
    c.is_nullable,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
    [Investment Data 1].sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    [Investment Data 1].sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Investment Data 1].sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Investment Data 1].sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.hurricane_landfall_2017')
```

Answer (score 0):

In each query that you use, you have to set the database that you want the sql-server come to.
We have 2 ways for that:
1. "Use" command (like what you wrote)
2. Select for the listbox (left side, at the top part) your database
Note that the "use" command it's more stronger from the listbox way.
I hope I helped.
Goodluck!